# Meaning of $c$ in the linear equation $ax + by = c$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I found: $ax+by=c$

What exactly does $c$ stand for? What does it do and why is $c$ important?
I googled everywhere but couldn't find an answer other than $c$ being a constant.

Comment: @JessicaTiberio Please [use MathJax for math variables](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22025/is-it-required-to-use-mathjax-for-simple-listings-of-numbers), like $C$ instead of `*C*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you filed this under Linear Algebra, I will take an LA approach towards it.

Your equation is the 2D analog of the 3D equation for a plane defined by its normal.  In 3D, a point can be represented as a vector $ \vec p = (x,y,z)$.  Another vector is $(a,b,c)$.  Suppose $(a,b,c)$ is the normal $\vec n$ to a plane passing through a specific point $ \vec p_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$.  Any point on the plane has to have the condition the the vector formed by it and $\vec p_0$ has to be perpendicular to $\vec n$:

$$ ( \vec p - \vec p_0 ) \cdot \vec n = 0 $$

$$ \vec p \cdot \vec n = \vec p_0 \cdot \vec n $$

$$ a x + by + cz =  a x_0 + by_0 + cz_0 = d $$

Because $\vec n$ and $\vec p_0$ don't vary, the value of $d$ is constant.  The value determines where along $\vec n$ the plane is actually located.

In the 2D case, the normal to the line is $(a,b)$ and $c$ plays the role of $d$.  In other words, $(a,b)$ tell the direction of the line and $c$ gives you the location.

Comment: Holy crap. This is a perfect explanation.

Comment: @Asperger, You're welcome.  Note that if $c=0$ then the line passes through the origin.  For every unit change in $c$ is another parallel line the same distance apart.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Forgot to do so yesterday. About that last comment about the unit change in c,  do you know any images that illustrate it? Have a bit trouble visualizing.

Comment: @Asperger,  Simply plot a few lines and you'll get the pattern immediately.  Assume $a$ is not zero.  Draw a line through the origin with a slope of $-b/a$.  Next, plot a point on the y-axis at $1/a$.  Draw a line parallel to the first through that point.  That line is where $c=1$.  Now plot a point on the y-axis at $2/a$ and draw another parallel line through it.  Yep, that's the line for $c=2$.  See the pattern?  The y-axis means $x=0$, plugging that into the equation gets you $y=c/a$.  If $a$ is zero do this with $b$ instead with $y=0$.  If $b$ is also zero, you have a meaningless equation.

Comment: Indeed, I get it now. This is really useful because now I understand it perfectly. Im computing those lines in code now : )

Comment: @Asperger, Good.  For icing on the cake draw the vector $(a,b)$ on your graph as well.

Answer (score 0):

If $b=0$, then $$ ax+by=c \iff ax=c $$

which means $x$ is a constant.

Otherwise, $$ y= c/b-(a/b) x $$

That is $c/b$ is the initial value  of $y$ associated to the $x=0$, that is the $y$ -intercept.

Answer (score 0):

There is a straight explanation for it. First write the equation in slope intercept form:-

$$y=-Kx+J$$
I am using $K$ in place of slope and $J$ for y intercept.( Note I used -K so that you get the desire form orstill you would get the standard for! But for the sake of simplicity I would use -K)

Now :-

$$y+Kx=J
\\ \implies Kx+y=J$$

Slope is generally a fraction if it is a fraction you have B with y or else your B would be 1 in standard form. But let us assume that $K$ is a fraction equal to $\frac{A}{B}$

Then :-

$$\frac{A}{B}x+y=J$$
I would multiply both sides by B.

$$B(\frac{A}{B}+y)=BJ$$
I would simplify it directly in the next equation so please see it.

Let  ***$BJ = C$***

Then by distribution of B and the above assumption:-

$$Ax+By=C$$

And here is our Answer. If I took K positive slope then it would have been -Ax instead try yourself.